# Unsupported operand all math symbols and floats?

Tags: python, geany

My main error that I am getting is;

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

```
#Name variables/imports. Ask usr for scale lengh and num of frets
import math

scalelenth = input ("please inter a number for scale \n > " ) 
constnum = 17.817

#Calculate Fret one distance 
fretum = scalelenth / constnum 

print("this is scale lenth %d " %scalelenth)
```

Comment: I clicked on the code button and it did not work. How do I edit to try and figure out what I did wrong? Is there no edit button?

Comment: I think you need to be doing this: `float(input(....))`

Comment: Thankyou I really appreciate the quick response. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, `input()` returns a string.  You need to convert it to a number:

```
scalelenth = int(input("Please enter a number for scale \n > "))
```

If you want to include decimals, use `float()`:

```
scalelenth = float(input("Please enter a number for scale \n > "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string to float first and then do your calculation:

```
fretum = float(scalelenth) / constnum
```

Answer (score 0):

`scalelength` is a string (assuming you are using python3.x) and `str * float` doesn't work (what would it do?)

The fix is to convert the string into a float:

```
fretum = float(scalelength)/ constnum
```